# How to convert a python project to ipynb format notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a python machine learning project in a folder. I want to change the whole project into ipynb formate notebook. Actually I want it in Google Colab.

Answer (score 0):

Use p2j to convert Python source code to Jupyter Notebook.

From the command line, run

```
pip install p2j
```

then go to the directory where your file is located. -->( for example-> cd downloads, if the file is in download directory)

then run

```
p2j myscript.py
```

This will create a myscript.ipynb file.

Comment: Isn't it only work for a single .py project?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to achieve your goal in easiest way:

1. *Compress your folder to a zip file*
2. *Open google colab and create a new notebook*
3. *On the left side there will be a menu, click the upload button on the upper left corner of that menu and upload the folder.*
4. *User ' !unzip /path-to-file' to unzip the whole folder.*

Ps: you can copy the zipped folder path by right clicking on it and it will give you a few options including 'copy path'.